# express js static file from different path than root

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, coffeescript

I have a page asking for these files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/js/app.js"></script>
```

and I've set up the express static route as follows

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()

app.use '/vendor/js', express.static './node_modules/framework/'
app.use '/vendor/css', express.static './otherFramework/'

app.get '/page/:num', (req, res) ->
    page = parseInt req.params.num, 10
    res.render 'list', #list is a jade file that extends a common layout.jade, the same as the '/' route
        start: page
        end: ++page
    return
```

when I open the page `'/'` everything works fine, but now I want to implement another MVC-like route like `'/page/:num'`, and express is asked this new route as base path for my requested external files, ex: (from the server log)

```
/page/1/vendor/css/style.css - 200
```

and this obviously doesn't work.

How can I tell express to search in the root? I tried to use a `~` before the path but it didn't work.

Comment: Express doesn't generate the paths that end up in your HTML, so if your HTML contains `/page/1/vendor/css/style.css` it's coming from somewhere else (template perhaps, or you're using Express subapps and adding the static middleware for each subapp, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: You're right, I got that path from the server log

Comment: Can you show how you add the `/page/:num` handler to your app? Also, I assume that, as you are stating, the resource URI's in your HTML are absolute (that is, they start with a `/`).

Comment: I think the issue is caused somewhere in your templates. Can you show the template code that generates the `<link>` and `<script>` elements?

Comment: oh no those are static

Comment: But still in a Jade template (or layout), I assume?

Comment: I mean the url is static, it's not rendered by jade

Comment: `link(rel = 'stylesheet', href = '/vendor/css/style.css')`?

Comment: yes exactly. I've answered myself, but thank you anyway

Comment: You worked around the problem, but you didn't fix it :P

Answer (score 0):

in the `app.js` (main file) file,before application routes, add these lines :

```
app.get('*/vendor/css/style.css', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/vendor/css/style.css');
});

app.get('*/vendor/js/app.js', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/vendor/js/style.js');
});
```

Comment: That (somewhat) fixes the symptoms, but not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

@akram-saouri 's answer was almost exact: I ended up using this configuration:

```
app.use '*/vendor/js', express.static './node_modules/framework/'
app.use '*/vendor/css', express.static './otherFramework/'
```

for all the app and it worked like a charm